# How to extract a value from JSON in Presto?

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino

{"xyz":{"aaabc":"80.00","ccccd":null,"npccc":"0.00","txnid":"pca","diccsc":"0.00"}}

I have to extract xyz where xyz is dynamic variable ( in some case it maybe xyz in other it may be abc or anything )

Comment: since, you can't use name of variable. How is this identified? By some regex or by index (being only string)?

Comment: You can try string concat from second curly braces to second last curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a `varchar`, you can

- convert to `json`
- cast to `map(varchar, json)`
- extract entries from a map with [`map_entries`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_entries)
- get the first one

```
SELECT map_entries(CAST(CAST(my_column AS json) AS map(varchar, json))[1]
FROM ...
```